# Flutter: ClipRRect vs Container with BoxDecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that ClipRRect has additional options like custom clipper. But if I need just a simple border radius is there any performance difference? Which one is more recommended?

Comment: go for DecoratedBox , clip is very expensive.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to create a rounded border, you must use clippers only in the last situation, when containers may not help. For example, images can draw over rounded borders, so you have no other option unless clipping the image.

Answer (score 2):

how about shape, shape vs cliprrect

```dart
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Test'),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide.none,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
  ),
)
```