# Container borderRadius vs ClipRRect borderRadius

Tags: flutter, dart

Both `Container` and `ClipRRect` has `borderRadius` property, but sometimes `Container` fail to work. Here is the example.

**Not working**

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
  child: RaisedButton(onPressed: null),
),
```

**Working**

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
  child: RaisedButton(onPressed: null),
),
```

I want to know why `Container` fails sometimes and where else it can fail?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300100/flutter-cliprrect-vs-container-with-boxdecoration) is related but I am looking for a good explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) inserts a render object that modifies the render tree of the widgets in its subtree.

Subtree of `ClipRRect` **will be** affected and the corners will be clipped.

Hit tests for the widget itself as well as for its children will be performed with the clip path respected. Meaning that gesture recognizers (/ buttons) within the widget will not receive taps outside of the clipped area.

`ClipRRect` is relatively expensive, but is suitable to clip an image or other complex graphic elements that do not provide rounded corners setting on their own.

---

`Container` on the other hand, when used with [`BoxDecoration` and `borderRadius`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration/borderRadius.html) / `shape` set, simply draws a box with rounded corners on its background.

Subtree of such Container **will not be** affected by the background decoration of their parent widget.

Hit tests for the `Container` will be performed with `borderRadius` respected, providing "truly rounded" UI-wise tap experience for the container itself. However, children gesture recognizers are not exposed to the decoration settings - hence, gestures will be received as usual even beyond the "clipped" area.

Decorated container with `shape` or `borderRadius` set is preferable as it is relatively less expensive to draw and maintain, given that the clipping mask for the subtree is not needed.

---

In the end, I do have to note that neither way described here is the best way in your case.

To create a `RaisedButton` with rounded corners use [`RoundedRectangleBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html) for the [`shape`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/shape.html) property of your button.

e.g.

```dart
RaisedButton(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100))
  // ...,
)
```

Comment: By subtree do you mean child/children?

Comment: Way better than starting to draw my own custom clip path. Thanks for sharing!