# Border radius is not working container widget with tab view widget. i want out like shown in image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Please post your code how i can make container layout rounded from top-right and top left please for more see image.**[image]

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `Container` with `BoxDecoration`, or `ClipRRect` widget instead.

---

`Container` with border radius simply draws rounded box as its background and is best in terms of device performance.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(24), topRight: Radius.circular(24)),
  ),
  child: // ...,
),
```

---

`ClipRRect` on the other hand looks better as it clips itself & entire subtree to the form of a rounded box. However, in terms of performance it is rather expensive for the device to draw & maintain it.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(24), topRight: Radius.circular(24)),
  child: // ...,
),
```

---

For more information [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406128/6374527).

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thank you George for your precious answer but both methods are not working with my code. I have given try with both methods. if i use box decoration then container color and layouts are gone and for the cliprrect is not working.

Comment: In my case, Container is not working, ClipRRect is working, finally, so many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `BoxDecoration` to your code

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),   //use radius you want instead of 20.0
    topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)   //use radius you want instead of 20.0
  )
),
```

So overall your code will be

```
Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),   //use radius you want instead of 20.0
      topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)   //use radius you want instead of 20.0
    )20.
  ),
  child: //Child widget
),
```

Comment: Thank you mangaldeep for your reply but i have done with this method in my case it is not working.