# How can I draw a image with circular border in canvas?

Tags: canvas, flutter, google-maps-markers

I am currently working with canvas in Flutter for the first time. I have to do **an market for google maps** (*its just possible to do it using canvas or raw images for now*), using a custom image taken from the internet. I got something working  with the image and it looks like this:

[image: Current result]

But my expected result should have the image with a circular shape. It looks like this:

[image: Expected result]

**Does someone know how to do it?**

Here some code

Painter

```dart
class ImageEditor extends CustomPainter {
  ImageEditor({
    this.image,
  });

  ui.Image image;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async{
    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(0, -size.height*0.8), new Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.fill);

    final radius = math.min(size.width, size.height) / 8;
    final center = Offset(50, 50);
    Paint paintCircle = Paint()..color = Colors.black;
    Paint paintBorder = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = size.width/36
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paintCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paintBorder);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Main class

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';

import 'canvas_test.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ui.Image image;
  bool isImageloaded = false;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future <Null> init() async {
    image = await _loadImage("https://<link>");
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _loadImage(String photoUrl) async {
    final cache = DefaultCacheManager();
    final file = await cache.getSingleFile(photoUrl);
    final bytes = new Uint8List.fromList(await file.readAsBytes());

    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(bytes, (ui.Image img) {
      setState(() {
        isImageloaded = true;
      });
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  Widget _buildImage() {
    if (this.isImageloaded) {
      return new CustomPaint(
        painter: new ImageEditor(image: image),
      );
    } else {
      return new Center(child: new Text('loading'));
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First Canvas"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 90.0,
            child:  _buildImage(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could separate photo from circle below and make your photo round (using `CircleAvatar` or `Clipper`)

Comment: Instead of creating a custom Painter - use [`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) widget. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406128/6374527) to learn more about best practices for rounded widgets.

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky and George it is not possible to use widgets for google maps markers. If not it would be simple to do with **Clipper** or **CircleAvatar**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```dart
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async{
      final center = Offset(50, 50);
      final radius = math.min(size.width, size.height) / 8;

      // The circle should be paint before or it will be hidden by the path 
      Paint paintCircle = Paint()..color = Colors.black;
      Paint paintBorder = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.white
        ..strokeWidth = size.width/36
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
      canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paintCircle);
      canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paintBorder);

      var drawImageWidth = 0;
      var drawImageHeight = -size.height*0.8;

      Path path = Path()
        ..addOval(Rect.fromLTWH(drawImageWidth, drawImageHeight, image.width, image.height));

      canvas.clipPath(path);

      canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(drawImageWidth, drawImageHeight), new Paint());

    }
```

This solution allows you to make round image on the `canvas`.

Comment: Thanks! It partially works, It removes the borders but also removes the black point. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: Maybe this `..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center, radius))` isn't positioned correctly. Second oval has to cover black point, so it seems that it is on the wrong place. Set colored background for whole canvas and you can see where exactly is second oval

Comment: Maybe it have to be bigger radius for second oval

Comment: I was able to fix it. I removed `..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center, radius))` and changed the order of drawing. I discovered that the order can influence on if an element is hidden or not. I changed your answer with these modifications. I hope that you don't mind. Check if it looks good for you

Comment: Paint it before clipping - yes, good solution, I didn't think about it.

Comment: BTW, Thank you! It was really useful! :)